# Bootstrap MultiSelect - Not showing dropdown in Wicket Modal Window

Tags: jquery, wicket, bootstrap-multiselect

I have implemented [Bootstrap Multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#getting-started) which appears in a wicket modal window to choose certain options for a task. I am unable to open dropdown window to choose options on click of it. Strange thing is I am able to open it in the parent window of this modal window where another similar multiselect is available..

*Here is the code of a JS function for generating my multiselect box* -

```
var inputField = jQuery('#' + input);
    try
    {
        inputField
                .multiselect({
                    maxHeight : 400,
                    includeSelectAllOption : false,
                    enableFiltering : false,
                    buttonWidth : '100%',
                    dropRight : true
                });
    } catch (ex)
    {}
```

I see that appropriate bootstrap and bootstrap multiselect versions are available with this page. Unable to figure out the issue.

[image]

Comment: Most probably it is a CSS issue. It is either something about `z-index` or the famous IE+iframe issue with windowed and windowless HTML elements (if you use IE).

Comment: Ok @martin-g, Any solution for it? Increasing z-index for multiselect will fix that. Pls advise..

Comment: Use your browser Dev Tools to find the zIndex values for both the modal and the dropdown. Then you will know more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have applied a hack to fix this issue as nothing seems to be working in wicket modal window

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '[data-toggle=dropdown]', function() {
    var opened = $(this).parent().hasClass("open");
    if (! opened) {
        $('.btn-group').addClass('open');
        $("button.multiselect").attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
    } else {
        $('.btn-group').removeClass('open');
        $("button.multiselect").attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
    }
});
```

Bit of additional code to add, but It solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are having an extra closing bracket `}` in multiselect options try this,

```
inputField.multiselect({
     maxHeight : 400,
     includeSelectAllOption : false,
     enableFiltering : false,
     buttonWidth : '100%',
     dropRight : true
     // } remove this extra bracket
});
```

Snippet,

```js
$('#example-getting-started').multiselect({
  maxHeight: 400,
  includeSelectAllOption: false,
  enableFiltering: false,
  buttonWidth: '100%',
  dropRight: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>


<div class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display:block">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: My bad @RohanKumar. To make question simple, i have removed the extra attribute templates and then forgot to remove that extra }.. I have edited the question now. Problem is it don't even toggle class to open too.. It happens only in the modal window

Comment: It is working in my code snippet, may be some css property is overwritten on it. Check it in your browsers console/element tab.